# Unable to set visibility of constraintlayout to gone if string is null

Tags: android

I have paths in my `sqlite database` that i transform them in picture with `glide` library ..`the imageviews` are grouped in `constraintlayout` ..i want to set that constraintlayout to invisible if there is no path in mysqlite database..

code that'ive tried:

```
Public class Nostrils extends AppCompatActivity {
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mToggle;
private android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar mToolbar;
ExpandableListView expandableListView;
Database mDatabase;
private static RequestOptions noTransformOptions;
ConstraintLayout constraintLayout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_nostrils);


    mDatabase = new Database(this);
    mDatabase.open();
    Cursor cursor = mDatabase.getDatabase();
    startManagingCursor(cursor);

    String[] childFrom = new String[]{Database.DATABASE_CHILD_1,Database.DATABASE_CHILD_2,Database.DATABASE_CHILD_3};
    String[] groupFrom = new String[]{Database.DATABASE_GROUP_1};

    int[] groupTo = {R.id.group1};
    int[] childTo = {R.id.child1,R.id.child2,R.id.child3};

    SimpleCursorTreeAdapter simplecursortreeAdapter = new ExpandableListViewAdapter(
            this,
            cursor,
            R.layout.list_group,
            groupFrom,
            groupTo,
            R.layout.list_child,
            childFrom,
            childTo
    );

    simplecursortreeAdapter.setViewBinder(new MyViewBinder());

    expandableListView = findViewById(R.id.expandableListview2);
    expandableListView.setAdapter(simplecursortreeAdapter);
}

protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mDatabase.close();
}


public class MyViewBinder implements SimpleCursorTreeAdapter.ViewBinder {

    @Override
    public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {
        int viewID = view.getId();
        switch(viewID){
            case R.id.group1 :
                TextView groupName = (TextView) view;
                String groupname;
                groupname = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Database.DATABASE_GROUP_1));
                groupName.setText(groupname);

                break;

            case R.id.child1 :
                TextView friendName = (TextView) view;
                String friend_name;
                friend_name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Database.DATABASE_CHILD_1));
                friendName.setText(friend_name);
                break;

                    contactProfile.setBackgroundResource(0);
                }
                break;


            case R.id.child2 :
                ImageView url = (ImageView) view;
                String urls;


          urls = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Database.DATABASE_CHILD_2));
            ConstraintLayout constraintLayout=(ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
            if(urls!= null) {
                constraintLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);}
            Glide.with(Nostrils.this).load(urls).apply(noTransformation()).into(url);
            url.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Nostrils.this);
                    View mView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_custom_layout, null);
                    PhotoView photoView = mView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
                    photoView.setImageDrawable(((ImageView)view).getDrawable());
                    mBuilder.setView(mView);
                    AlertDialog mDialog = mBuilder.create();
                    mDialog.show();
                }
            });
            break;

        case R.id.child3 :
            ImageView url3 = (ImageView) view;
            String urls3;
            urls3 = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Database.DATABASE_CHILD_3));
            Glide.with(Nostrils.this).load(urls3).apply(noTransformation()).into(url3);
            url3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Nostrils.this);
                    View mView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_custom_layout, null);
                    PhotoView photoView = mView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
                    photoView.setImageDrawable(((ImageView)view).getDrawable());
                    mBuilder.setView(mView);
                    AlertDialog mDialog = mBuilder.create();
                    mDialog.show();
                }
            });
            break;


        }
        return true;
    }

}
 private class ExpandableListViewAdapter extends SimpleCursorTreeAdapter {
        private ExpandableListViewAdapter(
                Context context,
                Cursor cursor,
                int groupLayout,
                String[] groupFrom,
                int[] groupTo,
                int childLayout,
                String[] childFrom,
                int[] childTo) { super(context, cursor, groupLayout, groupFrom, groupTo, childLayout, childFrom, childTo); }

        protected Cursor getChildrenCursor(Cursor groupCursor) {
            return mDatabase.getID(groupCursor.getInt(groupCursor.getColumnIndex(Database.DATABASE_ID)));
        }
```

actibity_nostrils.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main3"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".Nostrils"
    >
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <include layout="@layout/navigationactionbarbleu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/expandableListview2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />

</LinearLayout>
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:id="@+id/nv3"
    android:background="@color/colorbar"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_header"
    >

</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

child.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="8dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/child1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="0dp"
        android:paddingRight="0dp"
        android:paddingTop="2dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/times"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"

        />

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/gridview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/child1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/child2"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/child3"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/child4"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.227"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/child2"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/child4"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.942"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/child2"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

The error msg:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference
```

But the app keep stopping when i open a child!
Thanks for the help!
PS i can't add full class(as was asked) without having too much text ..so ths bloc is unrelated and have no meaning

'Morocco has a population of over 33.8 million and an area of 710,850 km2 (274,460 sq mi). Its capital is Rabat, and the largest city is Casablanca. Other major cities include Marrakesh, Tangier, Salé, Fes, Meknes and Oujda. A historically prominent regional power, Morocco has a history of independence not shared by its neighbours. Since the foundation of the first Moroccan state by Idris I in 788 AD, the country has been ruled by a series of independent dynasties, reaching its zenith under the Almoravid dynasty and Almohad dynasty, spanning parts of Iberia and northwestern Africa. The Marinid and Saadi dynasties continued the struggle against foreign domination, and Morocco remained the only Northwest African country to avoid Ottoman occupation. The Alaouite dynasty, the current ruling dynasty, seized power in 1631. In 1912, Morocco was divided into French and Spanish protectorates, with an international zone in Tangier, and regained its independence in 1956. Moroccan culture is a blend of Berber, Arab, West African and European influences.'

Comment: It can’t find your constraint layout for some reason. Insert breakpoint on findViewById where you’ve initialised your constraint layout and check if it’s null even after assigning the value. Have you used “@+Id/gridview” in some other layout too?

Comment: @intelliJ Amiya an activity ..

Comment: Can you add full class. Just wanted to check the activity or fragment code to move on for next step

Comment: i'm new to android so i'll teel what i have done! i initialised the constraint as the beginning (after the class bloc) as:     ConstraintLayout constraintLayout;
then i've the added the bloc above ..is is correct?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Please paste your whole code of the activity

Comment: Also please share the xml. Wanna look at the id child1 element

Comment: Share full java class with xml.

Comment: @Jashwant Singh  i did past it (please see the edited post)

Comment: @Amiya see the edited post please

Comment: Remove the constraint layout written at the top as it seems it’s of no use

Comment: You should show `activity_nostrils` xml

Comment: i added the activity_nostils.xml file in the edited post

Answer (score 0):

try

```
ConstraintLayout constraintLayout=(ConstraintLayout) view.getParent()
```

instead of

```
ConstraintLayout constraintLayout=(ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
```

Reason is 
You are doing this under case R.id.child2
It means you need to access the parent of this view

Comment: Tried it but still facing same problem :/

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Comment: view in "ConstraintLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.gridview);" cann't be resolved

Comment: One last try please

Comment: is it okey dude ..i'll try your solutions ..no problem ..but again view in ConstraintLayout) view cannt be resolved

Comment: From where are you calling setViewValue method

Comment: i only have 2 Java file ..class database, second is the one included in this post(the activity) ..i'm new to adnroid so i can't give you with asnwer to that ..but i have only 2 java files. so everything is there above

Comment: can you zip and send me the project. I can fix it faster

Comment: vissu.info@gmail.com